# Trying to draw to applet in another class

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

Hi im a bit of a beginner to java programming and am trying to figure out how to draw a shape (oval) from another class to a java applet (I'm sure it's probably a simple problem)

the class with the applet i want to draw to:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

    public class PulsatingBalls extends JApplet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void init(){
    getContentPane().setBackground( Color.black );
    new ball(20, 20);
    }
}
```

and the ball class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class ball extends PulsatingBalls{
int x;
int y;

public ball(int y, int x){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Applet:

```
public class PulsatingBalls extends JApplet {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    private final List<Ball>    balls                   = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel jp = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                for (final Ball b : balls) {
                    b.paint(g);
                }
            }
        };
        jp.setBackground(Color.black);
        getContentPane().add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        balls.add(new Ball(20, 20));
    }

}
```

Ball:

```
public class Ball {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Ball(final int y, final int x) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since JApplet isn't double buffered, it's not recommended to override it's paint method, instead, use a JPanel and override it's paintComponent method

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok, I´ve changed it.